# PHP Mysql group by date from accumulative values

Tags: php, mysql, math

I have a table with ID, value1, value2, value3 and tstamp (TIMESTAMP format) and i'm trying to group by each day and find a total for each day, however all values are accumulative, which poses a problem, because sum(value1) doesnt give the right output, this is my code:

```
$sql = "select date(tstamp), sum(".$column.") from mash group by date(tstamp) order by tstamp asc limit 10";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$previous = 0;
$firstRun = true;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $difference = $row[1] - $previous;
  if (!$firstRun)
  {
     $strXML .= "<set name='".$row[0]."' value='".$difference."' color='AFD8F8' />";
   }
  $previous = $row[1];
  $firstRun = false;
}
```

Can anyone spot the issue in this code, its not erroring, its just giving wrong answers.

EDIT:

To clear up any confusion, this is the SQL:

```
 --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `mash`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mash` (
  `id` int(25) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `steam` int(25) NOT NULL,
  `bore_water` int(25) NOT NULL,
  `boiler1oil` int(25) NOT NULL,
  `boiler2oil` int(25) NOT NULL,
  `tstamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5362 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `mash`
--

INSERT INTO `mash` (`id`, `steam`, `bore_water`, `boiler1oil`, `boiler2oil`, `tstamp`) VALUES
(2, 436, 73, 15, 1, '2010-11-25 12:28:03'),
(3, 495, 74, 36, 1, '2010-11-25 12:38:04'),
(4, 553, 76, 58, 1, '2010-11-25 12:48:09'),
(5, 565, 77, 74, 1, '2010-11-25 12:58:05'),
(6, 584, 79, 78, 1, '2010-11-25 13:08:05'),
(7, 630, 82, 100, 1, '2010-11-25 13:18:11'),
(8, 686, 86, 130, 1, '2010-11-25 13:28:07'),
(9, 740, 89, 151, 1, '2010-11-25 13:38:07'),
(10, 780, 93, 173, 1, '2010-11-25 13:48:13'),
(11, 883, 100, 218, 1, '2010-11-25 14:08:10');
```

Comment: Couldn't you group by `DATE(tstamp)` then order by the last entry which would have the value you're looking for?

Comment: I dont know why it isnt working Brad, but on some points its giving minus results, which definitely is not right. I've tried desc and asc, neither work

Comment: @benhowdle89: I'm populating a demo DB on my end now so I have something to test against. Is it safe to assume you're looking to achieve "value1","value2", etc. from the latest (last inserted) entry on a daily basis (since the last is always the previous plus new value?)

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks for taking the time to answer this, see my edited answer :)

Comment: @benhowdle having looked at it now, I believe you're looking for the MAX() of each column, grouped by the DATE(tstamp). e.g. `SELECT DATE(tstamp), MAX(Steam) As Max_Steam FROM mash GROUP BY DATE(tstamp);`

Comment: ah ok, what will max give me?

Comment: [MAX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) should give you highest value from each column within the group (which I think is what you want)

Comment: ah, perfect, if i knew that MAX existed i would have used that! Thanks for your effort Brad, you havent put an answer for the Q, so i dont know where to accept!

Comment: I'll post a formal one just for anyone else that comes along this question. Plus to help maintain your accept rating. ;-)

Comment: Ha, i was more thinking of your rep but hey ho...

Comment: @benhowdle89: Try not to do it for the rep. The joy of this site is helping people, but also solving problems you may not come across in your own experiences & increasing your own person knowledge all-the-while. ;-) But answer posted, and glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I'm reading your table correctly, you're looking for the last entry of "value1" (or value2, etc.) which in-effect is the sum (judging by your mention of accumulative values)

```
+----+------+---------------------+
| id | val  | tstamp              |
+----+------+---------------------+
|  6 |    1 | 2010-01-02 01:00:00 |
|  7 |    4 | 2010-01-02 02:00:00 |
|  8 |    6 | 2010-01-02 03:00:00 |
|  9 |   15 | 2010-01-02 04:00:00 |
| 10 |   20 | 2010-01-02 05:00:00 | <-- this value
| 11 |    1 | 2010-01-03 01:00:00 |
| 12 |    4 | 2010-01-03 02:00:00 |
| 13 |    6 | 2010-01-03 03:00:00 |
| 14 |   15 | 2010-01-03 04:00:00 |
| 15 |   20 | 2010-01-03 05:00:00 | <- this value
|  1 |    2 | 2010-02-01 01:00:00 |
|  2 |    8 | 2010-02-01 02:00:00 |
|  3 |   16 | 2010-02-01 03:00:00 |
|  4 |   32 | 2010-02-01 04:00:00 |
|  5 |   64 | 2010-02-01 05:00:00 | <- this value
+----+------+---------------------+
```

Then you should be able to use MAX&DATE:

```
SELECT    DATE(tstamp), MAX(val)
FROM      mash
GROUP     DATE(tstamp)
ORDER BY  tstamp ASC;
```

Which will produce:

```
+--------------+----------+
| DATE(tstamp) | MAX(val) |
+--------------+----------+
| 2010-01-02   |       20 |
| 2010-01-03   |       20 |
| 2010-02-01   |       64 |
+--------------+----------+
```

Comment: Hi Brad, i'm aware you have given me a full answer, but i've had a thought. Because every value is always bigger than the value before it (it also never resets). The problem i've seen arise is that say for day 1 the max value was 3456 (hence the total for that day) well day 2 will start with 3456 and only increase. Therefore my graph that i've plotted keeps increasing because each total is also added from the previous day! Does that make sense? Any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are grouping by the date, it's going to group by the smallest increment of the date.  You should be grouping by the day of the date.  Something like:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(tstamp, '%Y-%m-%c') as ymd, sum(".$column.") from mash group by ymd order by tstamp asc limit 10
```

Which will give you a year-month-date format that it'll group on.  If you need access to the year month and day values individually do:

```
select YEAR(tstamp) as year, MONTH(tstamp) as month, DAY(tstamp) as day, sum(".$column.") from mash group by year, month, day order by tstamp asc limit 10
```

Comment: fyi, the [DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function perform the same outcome as your DATE_FORMAT.

Comment: Hmm, thanks Photon, how would this fit in with my code above?

Comment: Basically to replace the SQL query itself.  And sorry I missed the accumulative portion of your description, and I see you've got a working answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

The key part of your question is not the `GROUP BY` portion, that will work just fine, it is what you mean by accumulative.

If you mean that a certain column tracks the total amount of rain in a year for each day (ie, the number keep going up because the delta between two records is the actual rain that occurred on that day) then what you need to do is first get rid of the delta. The SQL is going to be a bit hairy no matter how you do it, so you're probably better off doing it in PHP, but here is me trying with SQL.

```
create temporary table foo select * from bar;

create temporary table non_accumulative
select b.id, b.rain - f.rain as "rain", rain_timestamp from bar b join foo f on (f.id + 1) = b.id;

select sum(rain), date(rain_timestamp) from non_accumulative group by date(rain_timestamp) order by rain_timestamp;
```

Of course you can do the same with sub selects, but I find the temporary tables are faster.